# why can i reach to subclass?

Tags: php

I have two class.

First class = database.class.php (sub)->vericek.class.php

Database.class.php is:

```
Class Database
{
    public function __construct($class)
    {
        foreach($class as $class)
        {
            require_once("sub/" . $class . ".class.php");
            $$class = new $class();
        }
    }
}

$database = new Database(array("vericek"));
$database->vericek->abc();
```

and vericek.class.php is:

```
Class vericek
{
    public function abc()
    {
        echo "try";
    }
}
```

I want to see "try".. but i can't..
I can see this error: Fatal error: Call to a member function abc() on a non-object in C:\AppServ\www\ozetizle\classes\database.class.php on line 32

How can i?

Comment: Pardon the logical question, but why a Database class used as a sort of loader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to assign it as `$this->$class = ...` because using `$$class` will be a local variable, just visible in your constructor.